# Pointer to Structure Returns Incorrect Value in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I've created a C structure type as such:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

I am trying to acces `len` from within a pointer to an intarr_t object I (apparently) successfully created.  Below are two files which I'm working with here...

intarr.h

```
/* Structure type that encapsulates our safe int array. */
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;

/* A type for returning status codes */
typedef enum {
  INTARR_OK,
  INTARR_BADARRAY,
  INTARR_BADINDEX,
  INTARR_BADALLOC,
  INTARR_NOTFOUND
} intarr_result_t;


// Create a new intarr_t with initial size len.  If successful
// (i.e. memory allocation succeeds), returns a pointer to a
// newly-allocated intarr_t.  If unsuccessful, returns a null pointer.
intarr_t* intarr_create( unsigned int len );

// If index is valid, set the value at ia->data[index] to val and return
// INTARR_OK. Otherwise, leave the array unmodified and return
// INTARR_BADINDEX. If ia is null, return INTARR_BADARRAY.
intarr_result_t intarr_set( intarr_t* ia, 
                unsigned int index, 
                int val );
```

intarr.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "intarr.h"

intarr_t* intarr_create( unsigned int len ) {

    intarr_t original;
    original.len = len;
    original.data = malloc(original.len * sizeof(int));

    //populate with values
    for (int i = 0; i < original.len; i++) {
        original.data[i] = i;
    }

    if (original.data == 0) {
        intarr_t* originalp = NULL;
        return originalp;
    }

    else {
        intarr_t* originalp = &original;
        return originalp;
    }
}

intarr_result_t intarr_set( intarr_t* ia, 
                unsigned int index, 
                int val ) {

    if (ia == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", "error: array is null");
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }

    else if (index) { //need to check bounds properly here with ia->len, but it won't work
        ia->data[index] = val;
        //printf("length of array: %d\n", ia->len);
        return INTARR_OK;
    }

    return INTARR_BADINDEX;
}



int main() {
    intarr_t* arr = intarr_create(11);
    intarr_t* arra = NULL;
    intarr_set(arr, 80, 420);
    return 0;
}
```

To check the index bounds in `intarr_set()`, I would like to look at index's value to see if it is between 0 and `ia->len`.  However, `ia->len` is returning 420 instead of 11, which main specifies.  Shouldn't `ia->len` have a value of 11 since `intarr_create()` produced an intarr_t object which points to `original` with a `len` of 11?  Why is this?  `val` is not part of the `intarr_t` structure.  It's just a parameter.  I'm attempting to operate on `len` of `arr` in the main.

For now I've written `if (index)` just to make the program compile correctly until this is debugged.

`index` in `intarr_set()` returns the correct value.

`val` in `intarr_set()` returns the correct value.

`len` in `intarr_create()` returns the correct value.

Even the `data` in `original`, `originalp` and `arr` contain the correct values.

`ia->len` DOES NOT return the correct value.

Why?

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: Lest we ever get tired [of reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
intarr_t original;
...
intarr_t* originalp = &original;
return originalp;
```

You return a pointer to a local variable. Local variables goes out of scope and cease to exist once the function they were defined in returns.

If you want to actually create an instance of the structure, you should dynamically allocate it (with e.g. `malloc`).